# Animated hamburger

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this JavaScript code that controls animated hamburger and my mobile nav menu. When I click on it, it opens the nav menu in mobile view and sets the body to overflow hidden.

Basically, when I click on the hamburger icon, it opens mobile nav menu and when I make a selection, let's say About page or home page, it goes to the About or home page and body overflow is set to auto. That’s what I want to see.

However, If I click on the hamburger icon, open the mobile nav menu and I don’t make any selection but instead click the hamburger icon again to close the nav menu, the body overflow is maintained hidden so I can’t scroll the page.

I want the body overflow to go back to auto if I don’t make any selection on the nav menu.

```
      var menuIcon = document.querySelector('.hamburger-icon'); 
      var navbar = document.querySelector('#header');

      menuIcon.addEventListener('click', function(){
      navbar.classList.toggle('change'); 
      document.body.style.overflow = ‘hidden’

     });
```

Any help please? Or is there a way to use classList.add and classList.remove instead of toggle to write something like below

```
    if(open){
        Navbar.classList.add(‘change’);
        document.body.style.overflow = ‘hidden’
    }else{
        Navbar.classList.add(‘change’);
        document.body.style.overflow = ‘auto’
```

Comment: You have a few typos:`document.body.sytle.overflow = ‘auto’` style is spelled wrong and you need to change the single quotes to regular single quotes (not fancy quotes). `'`

Comment: Thx for the reply but that 'style' error was not in the main code... its only here as I retyped the whole code again here

Comment: Your quote marks are still wrong. You'll continue to get typo comments until you fix your typos and still have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could try checking if class "change" exists on navbar or not

```
var menuIcon = document.querySelector(".hamburger-icon");
var navbar = document.querySelector("#header");

menuIcon.addEventListener("click", function () {
  navbar.classList.toggle("change");
  if (navbar.classList.contains("change")) {
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  } else {
    document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate... your solution above has solved my problem. Thank you so much